# How to use persistent heap images to make loading of theories faster in Isabelle/jEdit?

Tags: jedit, isabelle

Let's assume I have a directory `isabelle_afp` where a lot of theories are stored. This directory is a library and I do not plan to change the files in it. I want to speed up the start-up time of Isabelle/jEdit (by default, all theories in `isabelle_afp` my current theory depends on are processed anew).

How can I skip this step? The [system manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2013/doc/system.pdf) tells me to build a *persistent heap image*. What is the easiest way to do so?

And how can I tell Isabelle/jEdit to load this heap image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isabelle/jEdit in Isabelle2013 already takes care of building your heap images, by a relatively basic mechanism that uses the `isabelle build_dialog` tool internally (which has a separate entry in the cited documentation).

You have two main possibilities doing it without using `isabelle build_dialog` or the `isabelle build` power-tool manually:

- The jEdit dialog "Utilities / Options / Plugin Options / Isabelle / General" provides a choice for "Logic", with a tiny tool tip saying that you have to restart the application after changing it.  Doing that, the heap image will be produced on restart.
- The command line option `-l`, e.g. `isabelle jedit -l HOL-Word`

For AFP sessions you need to tell the system separately about session directories.  This can be done on the command line via `isabelle jedit -d DIR1 -d DIR2` or in your `$ISABELLE_HOME_USER/ROOTS` file (list each directory on a separate line).

A pure command-line solution would look like this:

```
isabelle jedit -d isabelle_afp -l Simpl
```

Note that in this example, `isabelle_afp` is a (relative or absolute) directory name, while `Simpl` is the logical session name.

Comment: To list available sessions use: isabelle build -a -n -v -d isabelle_afp

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set up a "session" for your `isabelle_afp` directory. This is done by creating a file `ROOT` (inside `isabelle_afp`) which contains an entry of the following shape (see also `isabelle doc system` Chapter 3: Isabelle sessions and build management)

```
session session_name = HOL +
  theories
    Theory1
    Theory2
    Theory3
```

This roughly means that the heap image `session_name` should be based on the `HOL` heap image and additionally contain the theories `Theory1`, `Theory2`, ...

Now invoke `isabelle jedit -d isabelle_afp -l session_name`. When done for the first time, this builds the heap image of session `session_name`. As long as nothing in `isabelle_afp` changes, any further invocations will directly start Isabelle/jEdit on top of the prebuilt heap image `session_name`.