# Cannot select built session image in Isabelle/jEdit

Tags: isabelle, jedit

This is a follow-up to

[loading a precompiled heap image in Isabelle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646108/loading-a-precompiled-heap-image-in-isabelle)

Now I am on Windows. I created a Nominal2 heap image into the standard location:

```
$HOME/.isabelle/Isabelle2015/heaps/polyml-5.5.2_x86-cygwin
```

I cannot select it in the Theories panel to load.

I tried to start `isabelle jedit -d ... -l ...` from a cygwin bash script but that did not work. The script contained

```
#!/bin/bash

isabelle jedit -d /cygdrive/d/phd/thy/Nominal2-Isabelle2015/Nominal  -l Nominal2
```

but id did nothing, jEdit did not come up.

How can I create an executable that automatically loads my prebuilt Nominal2 image? Or, let Isabelle/jEdit know that there is a Nominal2 image in the standard heap location?

UPDATE: I copied the image from the user's home directory to the main heap directory:

```
in /cygdrive/d/isabelle/Isabelle2015/heaps/polyml-5.5.2_x86-cygwin 

$ cp ~/.isabelle/Isabelle2015/heaps/polyml-5.5.2_x86-cygwin/Nominal2 .
```

and restarted Isabelle/jEdit but I could not find `Nominal2` in the menu for session images.

Comment: “But it did not work” – please be more precise.

Comment: Also, to my knowledge, the logic selector in the Theories panel is not working properly, at least it was not in the past.

Comment: I think the "not working properly" mentioned by Joachim was that you have to restart Isabelle/jEdit after selecting the image. Did you do so? Anyway, `isabelle jedit -l Session_Name Some_Theory.thy` should work if the heap image for `Session_Name` was really created.

Comment: @chris, the Nominal2 image was not in the list, that is my problem

Comment: The question remains: what sequence of commands did you use in order to "create a Nominal2 heap image in the standard location"?

Comment: isabelle build -v -b -d . Nominal2, as it is written in the referred SO question

Comment: For me (on linux) your approach works. Did you double check that whatever you gave as argument to `-d` is really the location of the `ROOT` file that contains the `Nominal2` session?

Comment: The printout of the command convinced me that I gave correct parameters: it listed all the necessary theory files and at the end the Nominal2.thy file. And it did create that heap image.

Comment: In the same directory in which you (successfully) executed `isabelle build -b -d . Nominal2`, execute `isabelle jedit -d . -l Nominal2`. What happens?

Comment: For the first time I got a window telling the processing of Nominal2 dependencies and the base image became Nominal2. Next time it started promptly with default(Nominal2). Thanks.

Comment: It works on Linux but now I cannot try it on Windows as my office enjoys a summer break, rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to assemble heap images manually and moving them around, you should let the system do it.  You merely need to tell it where to find session source trees, either by `isabelle jedit -d DIR` or permanently via some ROOTS file (in some already known session directory).

A good place is `$ISABELLE_HOME_USER/ROOTS`: just add the directory location (in Isabelle/POSIX notation) on a separate line, and the Isabelle/jEdit logic selector should know the new sessions after restart.

Then you can select a new session, and its heap will be built after the next restart of the application.